# View model properties has changing validation rules at run time

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, validation, attributes

I'm new to C# MVC and I'm trying to add some dynamic validation checks to my view models that are used in a form. For example, I have a string property called FirstName. I can add the attribute StringLength(10) and Required() to it.

My problem is, depending on some other field, the FirstName StringLength could vary from 10 to 20, etc. I still want to use the MVC validations but be able to modify it. I know that attributes are bound to the class so maybe I'm using the wrong thing.

I want the abilities for attribute validation but have it modifiable at run time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in an attribute have to be literals.  You can still use attribute based validation, but you will need to use the `CustomValidation` tag and point it at a method to use.  If it depends on multiple fields in the object, you will want to put this on the class rather than the property.

Comment: Thank you. This led me to figure out how to find a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can add validation attributes at runtime by implementing DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider:
[Dynamic Attributes  @ forums.asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1626496.aspx)